# ARR cache doesn't cache one specific page built by Umbraco CMS

Tags: .net, caching, iis, umbraco, arr

We are building load-balanced website on Umbraco CMS with ARR 2.5 on a balancing gateway. We are trying to use ARR disk cache to store some “heavy” pages on gateway making it work as a reverse-proxy.

The problem is that some pages are not stored in ARR cache even if they are covered by ARR Cache Control Rules with condition Cache Always.
For example, we have a rule to always cache all pages inside “about”- folder.

It seems like this:

Condition: Always

Time: 60 minutes

Host name:

URL: about/*

As a result, I see, that some pages are cached but one is not. I cannot see it on the disk in cache folder and “netsh http show CacheState” doesn’t show it as well. I open the page in browser and see that it takes more time to load it in compared with others in the “about”-folder.
The only difference between cached and not cached pages is in HTTP response headers returned to gateway by target backend servers.

For cached pages they seem like this.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["c101eed1-0a28-42ae-8428-5ac86c87dc10","969bfc9d-073c-419b-8141-447fd8a0d56c"]
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
Date: Sat, 05 Dec 2015 19:15:01 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 34246
```

For the page that is not cached they seem like this.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Content-Length: 255916
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sat, 05 Dec 2015 20:11:21 GMT 
Last-Modified: Sat, 05 Dec 2015 19:11:21 GMT
Vary: *
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["4901b30d-6738-4918-b04b-c7aac2dbc043","480638b0-11cd-481d-8fdc-2dd1689c0b8b","342f085b-61dc-45b4-8c76-4da634bacf63"]
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
Date: Sat, 05 Dec 2015 19:11:35 GMT
Connection: close
```

The only difference is in the “Vary”, “Expires” and the “Last-Modified” HTTP headers where the latter has exactly the time when the target backend server (that is behind the gateway) responded. The time is returned different for every HTTP response with the page.

HTTP headers are generated by Umbraco CMS/IIS and we didn’t configure them to send such headers. Actually, content of the page is not changed but ARR cache doesn’t cache the page even with condition Cache Always.
ARR Cache Control Rule is hit for sure – we see it because other pages from the “about”-folder are cached.

I’ve already looked through a lot of sites trying to find something about how ARR decides which pages to cache and which to does not but there is nothing to clarify my issue.

Please, help me to find solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of "Vary" HTTP-header on target backend server and the page started to be cached.